# How to set Oracle connection property "includeSynonyms=true" in Grails 3

Tags: oracle, grails, grails3

My Grails 3.3.2 application currently connecting to an Oracle 11g database and some of the data tables are synonyms with dblink that point to the physical table in another database. When the Grails application startup, below hibnerate exception was threw:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [col_in_tbl_with_synonyms] in table [tbl_with_synonyms]

Many articles say that the connection property `includeSynonyms` has to be set to `true` in order to let Oracle return the meta data so that hibernate can find the column definition. So I tried to set the `includeSynonyms=true` in different ways but still not getting it work and always getting above error, no matter I used ojdbc6 or ojbc8 driver.

I know I can set `dbCreate: none` to bypass the validation as workaround, but with validation can find out the mapping problem earlier which should be a good idea.

Below is my configuration for reference, any idea? Thanks!

**build.gradle**

`bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ['-Doracle.jdbc.includeSynonyms=true']
}`

**application.yml**

`spring:
    ...
    datasource:
        dbProperties:
             includeSynonyms: true
             synonyms: true
        connectionProperties:
             includeSynonyms: true
             synonyms: true
        connection-properties:
             includeSynonyms: true
             synonyms: true
hibernate:
    ...
    synonyms: true
    includeSynonyms: true
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        dbCreate: validate
        dbProperties:
            includeSynonyms: true
            synonyms: true
        connectionProperties:
            includeSynonyms: true
            synonyms: true
        connection-properties:
            includeSynonyms: true
            synonyms: true
        ...
        properties:
            ...
            includeSynonyms: true
            synonyms: true
            dbProperties:
                includeSynonyms: true
                synonyms: true
            connectionProperties:
                includeSynonyms: true
                synonyms: true
            connection-properties:
                includeSynonyms: true
                synonyms: true`

Comment: im having the same issue.  i want "validate", but i have to set it to "none" (and everything works with none, but no ideal.).  Here is a slightly different sugar syntax answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867141/how-to-set-connection-properties-includesynonyms/60867494#60867494