# How to set connection properties (includeSynonyms)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

My DB configuration in Spring Boot is done using yaml file:

```yaml
# Common
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: truecat
        format_sql: false
        ddl-auto: validate
        synonyms: true
        connection:
          includeSynonyms: true
#        CONNECTION_PROPERTY_INCLUDE_SYNONYMS_DEFAULT: 'true'
    database: ORACLE
  datasource:
    tomcat:
      max-active: 10
      max-idle: 10

# template only
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/DEV
    username: DEV
    password: ...
```

Initially I was facing

> Schema-validation: missing table

So I added `hibernate.synonyms=true`, now I'm getting

> Schema-validation: missing column

To solve that I'd need to alter connection like this https://gist.github.com/uggds/c3f0fa71037bc5177f60

Can I do that in configuration?

What I tried and didn't work

```
hibernate.connection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_INCLUDE_SYNONYMS_DEFAULT: true
hibernate.connection.includeSynonyms: true
```

Related: [DatabaseMetaData.getColumns returning an empty ResultSet for synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545646/databasemetadata-getcolumns-returning-an-empty-resultset-for-synonyms)

I tried to google for that, but I found nothing...

**edit:**

Additional test based on M. Deinum's answer:

I strongly believe, that

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.synonyms: true
```

and

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        synonyms: true
```

is the same, at least it had the same effect, when I used one or the other (both resulting in `Schema-validation: missing column`

I added

```yaml
  datasource:
    tomcat:
      max-active: 10
      max-idle: 10
      connection-properties:
        includeSynonyms: true
```

but I'm getting the same error

> Schema-validation: missing column

When I completely removed

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        synonyms: true
```

I'm getting

> Schema-validation: missing table

**edit 2:**

Trying setting properties on hikari connection pool

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: false
        ddl-auto: validate
        synonyms: true
    database: ORACLE
  datasource:
    hikari:
      connection-properties:
        includeSynonyms: true
```

I'm still getting:

> missing column [zone_definitionpk_id]

Just to test, when I replace synonym with view it's fine. Also when I turn off validation it's fine. I mean the functionality works.

**edit 3**

Take care of `connection-properties` vs. `datasource-properties` and with synonyms the validation takes longer (at least for me).

Comment: It is complaining about a missing column, so your column names don't match the properties/field/mapping info in your entity.

Comment: I did the debugging hibernate is not retrieving column information for synonyms, that's the root cause for `missing column` error.

Comment: Well either of those settings does something as your error changes. Are you sure you are using the tomcat connection pool? Which Spring BOot version are you using? Also `hibernate.synonyms` and `hibernate:  synonyms:` isn't the same as Spring Boot uses the properties from `spring.jpa.properties` as is. It doesn't parse the YAML beneath it (this has been and probably will be a source of confusion). The properties are used as is.

Comment: No, I'm not 100% sure tomcat connection pool is used. I see in logs `HikariPool-1 - Start completed.` is that the same or different? Also there is `Running with Spring Boot v2.1.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.6.RELEASE`

Comment: Please add that to your question. Well then obviously setting properties on the tomcat connection pool is pretty much useless. Instead use the `spring.datasource.hikari` namespace.

Comment: I configured `hibernate: synonyms:` or `hibernate.synonyms` under `spring.jpa.properties` as shown above...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `hibernate.connection` properties is useless. You should be setting them on the datasource instead. To set additional, non default, properties you can use the `connection-properties` property on `spring.datasource.tomcat`.

**EDIT:** You aren't using Tomcat connection pool but the default HikariCP. So setting tomcat properties is pretty much useless.

Adding the following in your properties

```
spring.datasoure.hikari.datasource-properties.includeSynonyms=true
```

or yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      datasource-properties:
        includeSynonyms: true
```

You could also set the corresponding hibernate property, however not as you do. You  need to set it through `spring.jpa.properties`. This is due to the fact that the `synonyms` isn't exposed as a property on the properties object used by Spring Boot. Hence you need to set it as a additional property.

**NOTE** it is importantto use the full property name `hibernate.synonyms` in this section, **don't** format it as YAML as that won't work!.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.synonyms: true
```

**EDIT (1):** As the pool used is Hikari and not Tomcatc changed to Hikari namespace and properties.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, but it is not working - I'll update the question.

Comment: Then you haven't set the proper properties. Also it is yaml so make sure that your indentation is correct!

Comment: I was carefull with yaml format, I tried also to parse using https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ it looks good, just didn't do the magic...

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Maybe I 'd suggest you to have there also the version for `tomcat` (especially if the properties are `connection-properties` and not `datasource-properties` as for hikari).

Comment: Thanks, using only `hibernate.synonyms: true` fails on column not found, but this hikari `includeSynonyms` property saved me!