# Where includeSynonyms=true connection property should be added

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

We are using synonyms in `Oracle` database. So `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` is not working. So to solve this I added `hibernate.synonyms=true` but with this also it is not working completely. When I search for solution online I got to know I have to add `includeSynonyms=true` to `JDBC` connection property. My application set up has `hibernate-ApplicationContext.xml` file, so I tried to add in `hibernateProperties` but no luck.

Error is `missing column [column] in table [table]`

Could some one suggest where should I add this exactly?

Application details:

```
DB:Oracle
Server: Tomcat
frameworks: Spring(4.3), Hibernate(5.1.17) (xml and annotation configurations)
```

EDIT:

```
<bean abstract="true" id="baseSessionFactory"   class="XXX.hibernate.infra.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="physicalNamingStrategy" ref="physicalNamingStrategy"/>
    <property name="implicitNamingStrategy" ref="implicitNamingStrategy"/>
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="bdmsTransactionInterceptor"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- General hibernate properties - START -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.integration.envers.enabled">${hibernate.enable.audit}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister">${hibernate.enable.audit}</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change">${hibernate.enable.audit}</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy">org.hibernate.envers.strategy.${bdms.hibernate.strategy}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">${jdbc.fetchSize}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${jdbc.batchSize}</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.factory">#{validator}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.synonyms">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.includeSynonyms">true</prop>
            <!-- General hibernate properties - END -->
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="XXX.**.common.model"/>
    <property name="hbmFileTemplate" value="queries*.hbm.xml"/>
    <property name="mappingResources" ref="mappingResources"/>
</bean>`
```

DataSource: ${datasource.class.name}= com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="${datasource.class.name}"
          destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:user="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" p:initialPoolSize="${datasource.initial-pool-size}" p:maxPoolSize="${datasource.max-pool-size}"
          p:acquireRetryAttempts="5" p:acquireRetryDelay="3000"
          p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="300"
          p:debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true"
          p:maxAdministrativeTaskTime="600"
          p:numHelperThreads="5"
          p:testConnectionOnCheckout="${test.connection.on.checkout:false}">
    </bean>`
```

Comment: share the configuration that you have tried

Comment: Please check my EDIT

Comment: Assuming you are using an external datasource setting `hibernate.connection` properties are useless. You need to configure that on the datasource.

Comment: Our application is using `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` which is not accepting this property. Adding that config also in the question.

Comment: may be this answer will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867141/how-to-set-connection-properties-includesynonyms

Comment: this link had the answer in my case